# How can I import from JSON file to database using Microsoft Azure?

Tags: json, azure

I am trying to import from a JSON file to a database in Microsoft Azure, using pipeline. I can convert a lot from the JSON file, but I get an error when trying to import a Number value with decimals from the JSON file.

This is a part of the JSON code:

```
{"Email":"example@mail.com","Longitude":12.6026244,"Latitude":66.0176966,"HomePage":"www.webpage.com"}
```

When I try to run debug on the Pipeline it shows this error message:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'Longitude' contains an invalid value ''. Cannot convert '' to type 'Double'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'

The database has the type of Double where Longitude and Latitude values are supposed to be. Is the problem that Azure doesn't recognize type of the JSON number? I don't understand

Comment: using pipeline --**Does this mean ADF pipeline?**

Comment: yes, Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Comment: What happens when you enclose the numeric value in `double quotes`, ie "Longitude" : "12.6026244", and so on ?

Comment: That may work, but I want it to work wihout using double quotes. The JSON file contains hundreds of similar objects with longitude and latitude values similar as the example above.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because one of the documents in the Json array, has `''` empty string in longitude field. And longitude column in SQL database is of double type.

[image]

In order to solve this, you can use dataflow activity and check if data in longitude field has `''` empty string then replace it with null. Below are the steps to do this.

- Take the source transformation. Sample dataset is taken as in below screenshot.
  [image]
- Then take the derived column transformation and give the expression for Longitude field as `iif(Longitude=='',toFloat(null()),toFloat(Longitude))`. This will replace `''` to null. if it has float value, same value will be assigned.
- Then take SQL database dataset for sink transformation.

When the pipeline containing the above dataflow is executed, data is copied to SQL database without any error.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer! I am trying to do as u said, but i get an error in the derived column transformation. Please see post below.

Comment: I get an error at the derived column transformation stage. It says: "Expression's type 'string' is not matching with required type 'double'"

Screenshot of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW395.png

Comment: Could you try this, `iif(Longitude=='',toString(null()),Longitude)`

Comment: That did not work. Got this error: "Expression type could not be evaluated, correct the expression."

Comment: It works for me. Could you also try with case statement instead of iif?  Refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#case) for syntax of case.